# Why does my component show as Anonymous in React components dev tool

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I've read a few examples of this but couldn't find an answer that made sense.
I have a React component tree which is showing some components with their component names but others as just Anonymous.

I can't understand why.

The components showing as Anonymous are declared as:

```
  export const AddUserButton: React.StatelessComponent<{
  title: string;
  test?: string;
  onClick(): void;
}> = ({ title, test, onClick }) => (
  <CommonUserButton
    title={title}
    test={test}
    onClick={onClick}
  />
);
```

A simple example and explanation would be good thanks.

Comment: What does mean `Anonymous`? Its a hash or something?

Answer (score 0):

Babel transpiles components slightly different based on how you declare them. You should have the correct `displayName` if you declare like this:

```
// NOTE: React.StatelessComponent<T> is deprecated!
const AddUserButton: React.FunctionComponent<{  
  title: string;
  test?: string;
  onClick(): void;
}> = ({ title, test, onClick }) => (
  <CommonUserButton
    title={title}
    test={test}
    onClick={onClick}
  />
);

export default AddUserButton;
```

You can also try to set the displayName yourself by doing `AddUserButton.displayName = "AddUserButton";`.

Comment: What if the file where the component is declared isn't the default component but there are multiple small components being exported?

Comment: You can also try to set the displayName yourself by doing AddUserButton.displayName = "AddUserButton";. - where would I do this? do you mean in the browser console or in the component declaration file?

Comment: This also works with `export const { ComponentA, ComponentB };` or any other explicit export syntax. The point is separating the definition and export steps. Anywhere in the file after the component definition should work for `Component.displayName = "name";`

Comment: Thanks - do you have any references for why this happens? From your answer am I right to think it's only babel that causes this issue in transpiling?

Comment: Can't find it, but it's definitely to do with Babel's transformer, since in normal operation this is the step that automatically sets `displayName` on react components that don't explicitly declare it. You may want to type your component as `React.FC<T>` instead of `React.StatelessComponent<T>`, since the latter is deprecated: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/992608c1c494f1bd3f3b74a1664f8258506bbd14/types/react/index.d.ts#L542

Comment: Thanks, I notice it doesn't happen like this for every component that's exported inline though, do you know why it only happens in some cases if the way to fix it is to separate the export from the function?